# Clustering pins with Cesium used in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, cesiumjs

How can I integrate Cesium [EntityCluster](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/EntityCluster.html) with my React component and have the clustering updates render?

My project is structured to have React components rendering Cesium content like in [this example](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/03/declarative-earth-part-2-cesium-react/). My data source for pin locations is currently contained as an array of coordinates and text information in a Redux state. I am trying to use the [code example](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Clustering.html) from the Cesium Sandbox with my data in a separate React component by changing the dataSourcePromise to:

```
//pinArray is a Redux state    
var datasource = new Cesium.CustomDataSource(pinArray)
```

There are no errors in the console and the CustomDataSource console logs my data as an array in _name. The pin clustering is not working and/or not being updated in the React rendering.